# is it possible to check the time that l application start to using port and established

Tags: linux, networking, rhel, netstat, port

From the following netsta we can see that Air_metal application is using port 50070 and established

```
# netstat -anp | grep :50070 | grep ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 100.14.74.11:48148     100.14.74.12:50070     ESTABLISHED 29455/Air_metal
```

is it possible to check the time that Air_metal application start to  using port 50070 and established

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check process number using the port ; then with process number you can go and read /proc//sched and get in milliseconds the stats.

```
root@zaphod:/tmp# netstat -anp | grep -i postgr
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      904/postgres
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      904/postgres
udp6       0      0 ::1:49729               ::1:49729               ESTABLISHED 904/postgres
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     13146    904/postgres         /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
root@zaphod:/tmp# head /proc/904/sched
postgres (904, #threads: 1)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
se.exec_start                                :     346550579.786859
se.vruntime                                  :         67740.577403
se.sum_exec_runtime                          :         14266.931943
se.nr_migrations                             :                11174
nr_switches                                  :                69572
nr_voluntary_switches                        :                69407
nr_involuntary_switches                      :                  165
se.load.weight                               :              1048576
root@zaphod:/tmp#
```

so I check

```
heroot@zaphod:/tmp# dc
346550579 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / pq
4
```

I obtain around 4 days on this calculator
If I check my uptime (my postgres example starts at boot) so it would be equal (4days)

```
root@zaphod:/tmp# w
 21:46:44 up 4 days, 18 min,  4 users,  load average: 0.29, 0.65, 0.72
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
francois tty7     :0               Thu21    4days 28:10   0.05s /bin/sh /etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc -- /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc
francois pts/1    tmux(7598).%0    Thu21    2:55m 30.29s 30.20s irssi
francois pts/2    tmux(7598).%1    Fri21    2.00s  0.21s 11.34s tmux
francois pts/3    tmux(7598).%2    18:17    2:37m  0.13s  0.13s -bash
root@zaphod:/tmp#
root@zaphod:/tmp# #IT IS OK
```

That's OK. my example process is using is port since 4 days.